# Is there a way to write a for loop that selects sets of columns with different strings that end in the same integer? (proteomics data)

Tags: r, dplyr

I have a large dataframe with hundreds of columns. I would like to use dplyr to add a new column to this dataset with the results from a mathematical transformation.

This is a proteomics dataset where I ran multiple TMT mixes on the mass spec at once (this detail doesn't matter, but may be helpful for people who are familiar with LC-MS/MS data). Because of this I have several columns labeled "reporter intensity [0-10] batch [1-7]", I also have columns "iBAQ batch [1-7]".

For each reporter intensity column [0-10] of each batch, I want to create a new column with the result of this transformation:

(value of cell) x (iBAQ of batch)/(sum of every cell in the row from the same batch)

The original data looks like this:

```
dat <- structure(list(RIC.1.batch.1 = 1:2, RIC.2.batch.1 = c(3L, 5L), 
    RIC.1.batch.2 = 4:3, RIC.2.batch.2 = 5:4, iBAQ.batch.1 = c(12L, 
    15L), iBAQ.batch.2 = c(13L, 17L)), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", 
"tbl", "data.frame"))

# A tibble: 2 x 6
  RIC.1.batch.1 RIC.2.batch.1 RIC.1.batch.2 RIC.2.batch.2 iBAQ.batch.1 iBAQ.batch.2
          <int>         <int>         <int>         <int>        <int>        <int>
1             1             3             4             5           12           13
2             2             5             3             4           15           17
```

And I'd like to end up with columns like this added into the table with mutate:

```
iBAQfrac1batch1|iBAQfrac2batch1|iBAQfrac1batch2|iBAQfrac2batch2
3.00            9.00            5.78            7.22
4.29            10.71           7.29            9.71
```

I can't think of a reasonable way to write a function that matches every reporter intensity row of each batch to the iBAQ column of the same batch, without just grouping all of the columns manually. I just want to do this in a more intelligent way so that later on, if I had data with variable numbers of reporter intensity channels, I could still run the dataframe through the same code without wrangling it as much.

Can I write a for loop where I'd say, for every reporter intensity column ending in n, do the transformation with the iBAQ ending in the same value n?

Comment: It would really help if you would create a simplified version of the data and then show what you want the results to be. Also do you mean dbpylr or dplyr?

Comment: Thanks @Elin, I added simplified data and yes, I meant dplyr!

Answer (score 0):

How does this work for you?

It's a combination of nested apply's and regular expressions to pull out all you need:

```
library(dplyr)
library(stringr)

# does the calculation, extracts appropriate columns with regular expressions
fun <- function(dat, frac, batch) {
  tibble(key = frac, value = dat[[frac]] * dat[grepl(paste0("^iBAQ.*", batch, "$"), names(dat))] / sum(dat[grepl(paste0("^RIC.*", batch, "$"), names(dat))]))
}

# loop through data rows
apply(dat, 1, function(x) {
  # apply calculation to all combos of frac/batch
  d <- apply(tibble(frac = names(dat)[grepl("^RIC.*", names(dat))], batch = str_extract(frac, "\\d$")),
        1,
        function(y) fun(x, y["frac"], y["batch"])) %>%
    bind_rows()

  output <- d$value
  names(output) <- d$key
  output
}) %>%
  t() %>% # transpose the output from apply
  as_tibble() %>% # make data frame object
  setNames(str_replace(names(.), "RIC", "iBAQfrac") %>% # rename columns to match question
             str_replace_all("\\.", ""))

# A tibble: 2 x 4
  iBAQfrac1batch1 iBAQfrac2batch1 iBAQfrac1batch2 iBAQfrac2batch2
            <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>           <dbl>
1            3                9              5.78            7.22
2            4.29            10.7            7.29            9.71
```